# Spring mvc posting data to controller

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets, spring-mvc

This is a question what I have been wondering for quite some time.
Often enough I have my jsp which has to post some data to my controller. In this jsp I have some data I need to post to controller, but aren't touched by the user.. (ie, administration data like an ID). As far as I know there are 2 options to give the controller this data.

1. Use `<input type="hidden">` fields
2. Put everything in a session variable.

Option 2 has my preference since it requires me to type less code, and I can't forget hidden fields. Though this also has downsides, like another page overriding the session attribute.

What are your preferences? And are there any other options?

Thanks!
Davey

Answer (score 1):

I always prefer to make `session object` as small and as light as possible. I know its convenient but if your site is high traffic then these `session object` size will soon start adding to the `JVM instance` of the `Web Server`.

So I would prefer option 1 over option 2.